# Delveloping for Android high res screens, but supporting low res screens

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I've been developing Android games for the lower res screens (320x480) and then letting Android handle the density adjustments so the games work on high res screens.  It allows me to keep the size of my APK files small and I don't have to create multiple versions of every image in my games.  It actually works fine, the games still look nice on higher res screens.

However, my question is, is it possible to do the same thing, only backwards?  Can I develop for high res screens (800x480) and then somehow let android handle the density reductions automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

In your xml layouts, use dip values for sizes.

Example:

100dip = 
75 @ 120dpi
100 @ 160dpi
150 @ 240dpi

if you need a higher res resource for certain drawables, use the... 
 drawable-hdpi
 drawable-mdpi
 drawable-ldpi

The app will use the drawable from the correct resource folder depending on the screen's density.

Try not to use absolute widths and heights on certain elements if you can use FILL_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT.

Here's some good tips:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes, I know that we can put different sized images in their appropriate drawable folders, but is it possible to include only one image that's larger, that will be auto-resized down depending on the screen size.  Images are large, and I would like to keep my apps small if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it works the same. You put your resources in the appropriate directory and the system will downscale them accordingly.

Comment: So, if I have an 800x480 image in the hdpi folder, and someone is using a 320x480 screen it will auto-resize down?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. There are a couple subtilities though that you should be aware of: read about them at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html