# How to get killer graphics on an android game?

Tags: android, graphics

In games like Angry Birds, they have really crisp graphics. I want my game to have graphics like that. Could someone give me a couple of pointers regarding this?

My basically consists of a spaceship and asteroids. I've drawn large vector images for these components (800 px X 800 px) with transparent backgrounds. I've saved the file as a .png but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Are vector images the right way to go for getting crisp game elements like in Angry Birds?

Would the following steps be correct:
1. Scale the image down to match the size of the object in the game.
2. Save the image in the res/Drawables folder?

I think this must be a really basic question so pardon my ignorance and thanks for your help.

Comment: killer graphics? buy some ammo :)

Comment: Are you looking for a way to render things to the screen, or asking about the assets themselves? Because images created from vector-art are only as killer as they're designed, and the size they're saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use high resolution, large images and scale them in your game. You will be dealing with a variety of devices and will thus have to take into account the varying screen resolutions/sizes. You need to have the game programmatically decide what image sets to use, otherwise you could have great looking graphics on one device but nasty images on a different device.

This question should have everything you need: [Delveloping for Android high res screens, but supporting low res screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979981/delveloping-for-android-high-res-screens-but-supporting-low-res-screens)

Comment: NO he doesnt have to do any such thing programmatically. The different resource sets can be auto matically selected by the Android runtime - its the entire point of the resource selection subsystem. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html